# How do I debug python module loading?

Tags: python, plugins, python-3.2

I'm trying to port)[cwiid](https://github.com/abstrakraft/cwiid) from python 2.7 to 3.2.
It uses a lot of deprecated stuff so I have to change a lot of stuff in order to have it work with 3.2. Right now I'm stuck because of a load error. With a python 3.2 environment and the library installed to the package repo I do:

```
prompt: echo "import cwiid" | python -
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_cwiid)
```

Besides blind searching in the source code, **where does python expect the PyInit_cwiid** method?

In the source code for example there is the `py_plugin.c` which contains a `py_init` method.